# Handlebar helper to iterate every X number of items

Tags: ember.js

I am iterating over a list of items:

```
{{#each myList as |myItem|}}
    ...do stuff...
{{/each}}
```

But I want to grab every 4 items. Something like this:

```
{{#each myList as |item1 item2 item3 item4|}}
    ...do stuff...
{{/each}}
```

I tried this, and it doesn't work. Is there a way to grab every X items? If so, is the solution scalable?

Comment: It should have been nice if you comment about different answers provided below regarding this question. did you try anything different? did not answers provided help you at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars does not support this directly.  I would recommend using a computed property on some object.  Here, I'm referring to `model` as the array, but it could be anything:

```
setSize: 4,
modelSet: Ember.computed("model", () => {
  let model= this.get('model');
  let setSize= this.get('setSize');
  let offset= 0;
  let result= [];

  while (offset < model.length) {
    result.push(model.slice(offset, offset+setSize));
    offset+= setSize;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now, when iterating in the template:

```
{{#each modelSet as |items|}}
  {{item.0}} {{item.1}} ...etc...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This is essentially the solution I had to go with.

Answer (score 0):

If fixed size of 4 for splitting is good for you it is easy to achieve what you want with a tagless component. Please check out the [following twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1b6bfeec6f597dd870cd16042d4e3aa2?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.each-by-4.hbs). `each-by-4` component that makes use of `each-helper` internally does just what you want and hence it is a component you can just reuse it in your application easily.

However; if fixed length 4 is not good enough and you need dynamic splitting length (I mean sometimes 3, other times 5, and so on) it is really hard to achieve what you want if not impossible. I mean:

```
{{#each myList as |item1 item2 item3 item4|}}
    ...do stuff...
{{/each}}
```

If the following is good enough for you in terms of dynamic splitting size;

```
{{#each-n list 4 as |subList|}}
    {{subList.item1}} {{subList.item2}} {{subList.item3}} {{subList.item4}}
{{/each-n}}
```

Please check out the `each-n` component within the same twiddle I have provided. This approach seems to be more reusable; since it allows any size splitting. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I will add my answer here, use [ember-loadash addon](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-lodash), to install run the below command,

`ember install ember-lodash`

To include required array functions alone, you can import it like `import _array from 'lodash/array';`

Either you can define `junkedList` computed property which depends on `myList`. or you can create it directly as junkedList using `_array.chunk` method.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import _array from 'lodash/array';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    chunkSpan: 4,
    junkedList: Ember.computed('myList', function() {
        return _array.chunk(this.get('myList').toArray(), this.get('chunkSpan'));
    }),
});
```

To iterate,

```
{{#each junkedList as |groupedItems|}}
   {{#each groupedItems as |item|}}  
     //design using item
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Another option, install [ember-composable-helper addon](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) `ember install ember-composable-helper` addon and use `chunk` helper,

refer: https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#chunk

```
{{#each (chunk 4 junkedList) as |groupedItems|}}
       {{#each groupedItems as |item|}}  
         //design using item
       {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Always there are multiple ways, but the choice is yours.